# Mysql get the common categories of products

Tags: php, mysql, filtering

I am trying to create a filtering sistem for products.

I have:

- products table
- categories table: id, id_parent, name
- associations table: id_category, id_product

I want to search the table of products and from the results to create the common categories that they have so they can be filtered even more.

How do I get only the categories that are found in all the products list?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: By "*only the categories that are found in all the products list*" do you mean that you want to list the categories to which every product is a member?

Comment: If the listed products have in common only the category "size", then only that category I should find.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id_category
FROM (SELECT id_category, COUNT(DISTINCT id_product) AS cnt
      FROM associations
      GROUP BY id_category ) AS t
WHERE t.cnt = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM products)
```

This will return all category ids that are related to *all* products stored in the  `products` table.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/673b1/2)